# How to make imageview in cardview align to left

Tags: android, user-interface

here is my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentPaddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/ic_open_in_new_black_48dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView android:text="in card view" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I hope one line with first ImageView and second TextView, but i get:

[image]

how to fix it?

Comment: simply set width & height of imageview to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `match_parent` in `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for imageview.
Change it to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout inplace of LinearLayout and user "alignParentLeft" for ImageView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentPaddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"      
          android:src="@drawable/ic_open_in_new_black_48dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:alignParentLeft="true"
        />
        <TextView 
          android:text="in card view" 
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```